# Why my React Hook doesn't work? It reloads with wrong value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is live example code https://codesandbox.io/embed/wonderful-moon-sc9o2

I want to implement sort of i18n (like [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com))

When I click "Change Language" button, I expect all my translations in different components are updated:

```js
// Example.js
// t.ui.btn - is a path to string token
// { ui: { btn: 'Change Language' } }

<button>{t.ui.btn}</button>
```

The `lang` variable in my hook is changed all right, but the hook doesn't propagate changes to the app. Instead it renders initial `lang` value.

You can notice how `lang` receives initial value in console.

What is wrong with my hook? How to fix it?

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Example } from "./Example";
import { Header } from "./Header";
import { useTranslation } from "./useTranslation";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <h3>{t.app.title}</h3>
      <div>
        <Example />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**Example.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "./useTranslation";

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState({ count: 1 });
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  function onClick(ev) {
    setCount(prevState => ({
      count: ++prevState.count
    }));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Clicks state: {JSON.stringify(count)}</p>
      <button onClick={onClick}>{t.ui.btn}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export { Example };
```

**useTranslation.js** hook

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { dict as en } from "./en";
import { dict as de } from "./de";

const useTranslation = () => {
  const [lang, setLang] = useState("en");
  const dict = {
    en,
    de
  };

  function changeLang(lang) {
    console.log("[useTranslation][changeLang] lang", lang);
    setLang(lang);
  }

  console.log("[useTranslation] lang", lang);

  return {
    t: dict[lang],
    changeLang: changeLang,
    lang
  };
};

export { useTranslation };
```

**Header.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "./useTranslation";

function Header() {
  const { changeLang, lang, t } = useTranslation();

  function onChangeLang(ev) {
    console.log("[index][onChangeLang] lang", lang);
    changeLang(lang === "en" ? "de" : "en");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onChangeLang}>{t.ui.changeLang}</button>&nbsp;
      <span>{lang}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export { Header };
```

**en.js** translations

```
const dict = {
  ui: {
    btn: "COUNT",
    changeLang: "CHANGE LANGUAGE"
  },
  app: {
    title: "Hook Example"
  }
};

export { dict };
```

**de.js** translations

```
const dict = {
  ui: {
    btn: "Anzahl",
    changeLang: "SPRACHE ÄNDERN"
  },
  app: {
    title: "Hook-Beispiel"
  }
};

export { dict };
```

Comment: Please change your title to one more specific to your problem

Comment: Please add the necessary code in the question itself instead of a third party link

Answer (score 1):

Hooks are intialised each time you call it from a component. When you are calling the same hook from `Header` and `App` two independent instances of the state `lang` is being created. Instead, what you require is React Context which can preserve the state across components.

```
const LanguageContext = createContext({
  lang: "en",
  setLang: () => {},
});

const LanguageProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [lang, setLang] = useState("en");
  return (
    <LanguageContext.Provider value={{ lang, setLang }}>
      {children}
    </LanguageContext.Provider>
  )
}

const useTranslation = () => {
  const langContext = useContext(LanguageContext);
  const dict = {
    en,
    de
  };

  return {
    t: dict[langContext.lang],
    lang: langContext.lang,
    changeLang: langContext.setLang,
  };
};

export { useTranslation, LanguageContext, LanguageProvider };
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/wonderful-moon-sc9o2) | [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: But `react-i18next` doesn't use `<Provider>` concept. And language changes in components without Provider. I don't understand why we need context here.

Comment: `useTranslate` from `react-i18next` [uses context](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/src/useTranslation.js) internally, Also from the docs: _The interesting part here is by i18n.use(initReactI18next) we pass the i18n instance to react-i18next which will make it available for all the components via the **context api**._ I think I have already explained the need for context here in the answer